# sampling data with equal frequency

Tags: matlab, sample

I have a label vector  `labels` which contains the label information for 60000 objects of 10 classes (each class has 6000 samples).

I need to randomly sample 1000 samples, but also guarantee that 100 for each class.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but do you really want to us to tell you how to subsample a vector in Matlab? Such like a simple loop??

Comment: Are they mixed up randomly? Are you sure it wouldn't make more sense to just pick 6000 samples uniform-randomly rather than cherry picking a certain number per class?

Comment: @Dan, I think uniform-randomly makes more sense. Anyway, it's a suggested setting in a paper. I just want to reproduce the result.

Comment: @Dylan in future I suggest you post code of your own attempts with your question to avoid the down votes and close votes. I've posted a short for-loop based solution.

Comment: @Dan, thanks for advice. At first, I just thought matlab have same function as `sample` in R language which this task can ben done in one line.

Comment: @Dylan I don't think `sample` in R can do this... but if you know the R then you should have also posted that syntax in your question. MATLAB may well have a function for this, but I doubt it as it's kind of a strange way to sample something. But also, pretty sure MATLAB's [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) is the same as R's `sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your data are sorted randomly? So something like this (I'll use only 3 classes, `1`, `2` and `3` for simplicity):

```
data = [ones(n,1); ones(n,1)*2; ones(n,1)*3];
data = data(randperm(numel(data)));
```

So now you want `m*3` samples with `m` samples of each class (where `m <= n`). The most natural way would be to be less strict about having precisely `m` samples of each class and to just pick `m*3` samples uniformly-randomly:

```
idx = randperm(numel(data));
sample = data(numel(data))
```

Note that if you have the stats toolbox you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html?refresh=true) instead of `randperm` for this.

But if you have to have exactly `m` of each sample then something like this should do it. Note my goal is to get the indices rather than the values as I assume that is more what you're after:

```
classes = unique(data);
k = numel(classes);
idx = false(m*3,1);
for class = 1:k
    %// find the element numbers for each element of that class
    idxForClass = find(data == classes(class));
    %// Shuffle them randomly
    idxForClassShuffled = idxForClass(randperm(numel(idxForClass)));  %// or numel(n)
    %// Pick the first m from the shuffled list
    idx(idxForClassShuffelled(1:m)) = true;
end
```

Now when you want the data back just do

```
data(idx)
```

or more likely something like `data(idx,:)` because your `data` is probably not a vector. In that case though, you will need to change the `numel`s in my code to `size(data,1)` or something like it